# Excel VBA Timestamp in predefined row when data is changed in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

What I would like to do is, when data is changed at any place in a column, stamp that column with the last time data was changed and the username of the person who changed it.
(Sorry if this has already been answered anywhere. I've had a quick search and can't find it. Also fairly new to macros and VBA or I'd probably be able to figure it out myself.)

[image: Image showing setup of Excel spreadsheet in its current form]

I would like the timestamp (could just be the date) to appear in row 9 and the username in row 10.

I've found a few macros that do this for recording the change in a column and have tried to alter the formulas so it works for a row, but then have it write the date under the one before each time. This is the code I tried (on a mock up sheet rather than the actual one – I deemed I could change the address later if I can find out how it works):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row = 4 Or Target.Row = 5 Then
        Cells(Target.Cell, 3, 2).Value = Now
        Cells(Target.Cell, 2, 2).Value = Environ("Username")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This VBA code should do what you need

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 8 And Target.Column >= 4 Then

        Cells(9, Target.Column) = Now()
        Cells(10, Target.Column) = Application.UserName

    End If

End Sub
```

You need to add this code to the worksheet itself. Click on `DEVELOPER` in the Ribbon then click `Visual Basic`. This will open the VBA editor.

Choose the worksheet on the left and then paste in the above code and save as a macro enabled workbook.

Any edits to rows 1 through 8 after column C should add a date-time stamp and current username to rows 9 and 10.

Comment: That works great thank you. By the looks of it I can then just add the following code to also have it update when I add the rest of the data below this section. (I suspect I'll be updating a few of school's spreadsheets now as it will make it easier to track who has made changes.

Here is the extra bit of code I suspect I'll use:
    
`code`
If Target.Row >= 11 And Target.Row <= 200 And Target.Column >= 4 Then

        Cells(9, Target.Column) = Now()
        Cells(10, Target.Column) = Application.UserName

    End If
`code`

Comment: That should definitely work! You could clean up the if statement a bit by just doing:

Comment: Target.Row <> 9 And Target.Row <> 10